# How to fix git autocomplete in Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: command-line, 13.04, git

In previous version of Ubuntu 12.10 when using `git` from command line autocomplete of commands, branches, tags... worked. After installing fresh Ubuntu 13.04 and git it does not work. What to set up to make it work again?

**Edited**

---

Git is installed using `apt-get install git`.
When I enter:

```
git i
```

and press <kbd>Tab</kbd> nothing happens. `init` is not completed.

Comment: Do you have the package `bash-completion` installed? If so, the package `git` should provide `/etc/bash_completion.d/git` which will aid in the bash completion. (Log out and log back in after installation to enable the environment adapt to the new files installed.) If this fixes your issue, then I'll write this as an answer.

Comment: yes it is installed - bash-completion is already the newest version

Comment: Okay, obvious things excluded then. Are you running as `root` or as a regular user account? Did you install git from the Ubuntu package (software centre or APT) or using another method? Does `git ini`+`TAB` get completed to `git init`? Please include all additional information **in** your question by **editing** it. This is a Q&A site, not a discussion forum, you see. :)

Comment: @gertvdijk might be right. Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18898614/394589 for your user

Comment: @pcu Its really a common problem faced , I could some how solve it , and I have also posted the same , please check if this solves your problem .

Answer (score 11):

I had the same problem with Ubuntu 13.04

This is how I solved it

To get bash completion you need to reinstall git-core along with bash-completion package and then restart your bash shell

```
sudo apt-get install git-core bash-completion
```

Once successfully installed , just run

> bash

By doing so new commands gets initialized in auto completion and it will start working .

Hope this helps

Comment: it works for Ubuntu 14.04 too.

Comment: Not worked  for me

Comment: It works for Ubuntu 16.04 as well. The `bash` is indeed important.